# powershell command/script to make servers in trusted zone

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have 2 windows server and both can ping each other. On both the servers I have created shared drive. When I access Server B share drive from Server A it prompt for user name and password.
I have added serverB in trusted host file of serverA and visa versa. But still its prompting for user name and password.
I want ServerA can access ServerB share drive without propting for password and visa versa. Kindly advice.

Comment: Sounds like you need basic information on OS and file system security. What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: Trusted zone is not gonna fix your problem. The 403 challenge is caused by NTFS permissions. Give the user account appropriate permissions on the shared folders and you wont get the challenge anymore. And I agree with @Bill_Stewart this is not the place for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the response!!! I need a PowerShell script or command via which we can pass username and password or make 2 servers accessible password less . Like we do in linux by added ssh key in authorised files ?

Comment: @Rohin thanks for the response !! I have given full permission NET SHARE ShareDatabase=C:\Database "/GRANT:Everyone,FULL";

Comment: Thanks everyone !! I used this command and it worked fine !!!Net use \\10.10.10.0\ShareDatabase "p@ssw0rd" /User:Administrator

Comment: Not a stackoverflow question.